# ng-select dropdown behind other elements

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

I use [ng-select](https://github.com/basvandenberg/ng-select) with Angular 4 and Bootstrap 4.

The dropdown menu goes behind my datepicker (ng-bootstrap).

[image: The problem]

I do not know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you tried to play with "z-index" of that element ?

Comment: Hi, yes on ng-select z-index: 1000000.

Comment: Try also to put -10000 index onto the other elements which are over the dropdown

Comment: Putting such high z-index values bad practise. There is no difference between having a difference of 1 or 10000 between to layers. It either overlaps or it doesnt. Keep the values as low as possible.

Comment: OK that works :) What good value could I put for z-index? (Thank you :))

Answer (score 6):

I fixed this issue by simply adding `appendTo="body"` on my `ng-select` :

```
<ng-select appendTo="body" 
    [items]="nature_structure_recherches"
    placeholder="Nature"
    formControlName="nature"
    [multiple]="false">
</ng-select>
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this by overriding ng-select's z-index for the dropdown:

1) I added the following to my component's scss file (i.e. the component that hosts the ng-select):

```
ng-select select-dropdown > div {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

(I had to specifiy both ng-select and select-dropdown in the css selector to increase the css specificty so it win out over ng-select's css, at least I think that's why).

2) I added `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` to the component's decorator so its css would also apply to the ng-select component.